# How to discover Font Type?

Tags: javascript, fonts, firefox-addon

Is there a way to determine the type of a given font (TrueType, OpenType, Type 1, Bitmap) using javascript?

Comment: How would the font be inputted/where's it coming from?

Comment: The code will be running inside a Firefox Add-on. I get the fonts available in the computer using the nsIFontEnumerator class.

Comment: I would assume if the info is anywhere, it would have to be in `nslFontEnumerator`...

Comment: It's not. There is a nsIFontMetrics class without an .idl making impossible to call it from JavaScript code.